# Anime about boy who can accelerate objects; also meets girl with wooden katana

Tags: gate-keepers

It's about a boy with a supernatural power. He discovered his power when he was attacked by a black monster. As he threw a can towards the black monster, his power was activated, and a circle figure formed in front of him, which accelerated the can as it passed through and killed the monster. He also met a girl with a wooden katana who had the same power as him.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty sure you're thinking of [Gate Keepers](http://myanimelist.net/anime/127/Gate_Keepers).

> It is Tokyo, 1969. Earth is under the attack of the "Invaders." Fortunately, though, the public is unaware of this. But to the secret orginazation, A.E.G.I.S., the threat is very real, and it is up them to stop this invasion. One day on his route to high school, Ukiya Shun observes a battle between a young girl and a group of Invaders. He ends up helping her and discovers that much like the girl, he possesses the ability to generate a "gate" of special power that only a few other people are gifted with. As a result, Ukiya then joins A.E.G.I.S. in an effort to recruit other Gate Keepers in order to protect the city, all while doing his best not to imitate his late father, whom he dispises.

The main character boy was trying to defeat the black iron ball monster attacking his house by throwing a can at it. He is the one with the wooden katana (Special Bokken Sword). The main girl uses a bow to fight.

[image: Episode 1]

Comment: Can you please expand on this answer by providing a short description about the series and how it matches to what has been asked in the Question (ie. which scene has the can accelerating though a circle and killing the monster, who is the girl with the wooden katana)

Comment: Next time, your answer should look something like the edit (synopsis is usually optional) instead of a one-liner containing only the name of the series, which is about as incomplete as a link-only answer (a reason for deletion).

Comment: He doesn't actually accelerate objects. His ability allows him to open the Gate of Gale, which lets him manipulate wind and project objects using the wind.